# Как использовать селениум в php без тестов

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужно автоматизировать заполнение одной формы. Сделать это через курл не представляю возможным, потому что там много динамических полей, которые шлются аяксом.
Не могу найти ни одной статьи, как бы можно было из пхп, через вебдрайвер открыть страничку, дождаться загрузки ассетов, залогинеться, заполнить форму и пр...
Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть https://github.com/scraperlab/browserext.

Comment: Также может помочь вот это: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver